# Possible to detect using trap command

Tags: linux, signals, bash-trap

I want to detect some command if they are used on my system. For that reason I use auditd on my Linux machine. But I can`t figure out if it is possible to detect the use of the trap command.

Maybe you can help me

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could tell us what you have tried so far and if there were any error messages etc.

Answer (score 0):

"trap" is a shell builtin and as such isn't directly visible to auditd (there's no corresponding syscall).